# operator overloading for built in dat types in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use bitwise "and" and some other operator to data type `c_uint32` in python.

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'c_uint' and 'c_uint'
```

I believe I get this error because Bitwise `&` is not supported for `c_uint` by the python library.

Is there any way in which i can add any overloaded operator to the built in data types?

Answer (score 0):

The `c_uint32` data type is only meant to communicate with a c library. It should only be used to convert to and from at the boundaries, the location you do that communication.

Thus, for bitwise operations, convert the type to native Python types first, such as an python `int`. Extracting the values for a quick bitmask operation isn't that hard:

```
c_uint32(c_uint32_value1.value & c_uint32_value2.value)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what for i am using the variable type. But i am processing some logic for which i need to do some bit operations. And i wanted to do that in a single line, so just wanted to avoid the additional stuff of converting.